# How do I extract API documentation from a Swift file?

Tags: swift

Swift has some ability to extract comments and documentation from a module.

[Automatically generate the Swift interface for a compiled module](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25005444/automatically-generate-the-swift-interface-for-a-compiled-module)

```
echo ":print_module CoreGraphics" | xcrun swift -deprecated-integrated-repl
```

How can I use these tools to print documentation for my own module?

Specifically, I'd like to use it in C.I. as a test of whether my modules are fully documented.

Answer (score 0):

$ sudo gem install jazzy

$ jazzy

in the directory containing project file for the framework of your making per this: https://www.appcoda.com/swift-markdown/