# How to open a .swiftmodule file

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

I want to check a public content of a `.swiftmodule` file from an iOS framework.

Here (https://lists.swift.org/pipermail/swift-users/Week-of-Mon-20160111/000827.html) I've found a suggestion to use `swift-ide-test`:

> You can use the swift-ide-test tool to dump the public interface for a
>   module, but the command-line interface is less pretty than it should
>   be:
>
> swift-ide-test -print-module -source-filename=dummy.swift
>   -module-to-print=MyApp
>
> …plus any -I or -F paths necessary to find your module and all its
>   dependencies. If you're on a Mac, you'll need to insert "xcrun -sdk
>   macosx" or "xcrun -sdk iphoneos" at the start to find the system
>   headers.

Unfortunately, when I try to run `xcrun -sdk iphoneos swift-ide-test` with Xcode 10.1, I get following error:

```
$ xcrun -sdk iphoneos swift-ide-test
xcrun: error: unable to find utility "swift-ide-test", not a developer tool or in PATH
```

Seems that this tool was removed from Xcode.

Any other ideas on how to open a `.swiftmodule` file?

Comment: Your not supposed to be able to see the source code for iOS.

Comment: I want to check if my custom iOS framework is compiled correctly

Answer (score 8):

After few hours of struggling, I've found an IMPLICIT way of checking a public content of modules from an iOS framework.

The trick is done by using `:print_module` command inside the Swift REPL.

More precisely, you need to launch Swift REPL with a path to your framework:

```
swift -F <path to a folder with LibName.framework> -deprecated-integrated-repl
```

Now you can use `:print_module` command with a name of your framework:

```
(swift) :print_module LibName
```

Sources:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/27882120/2241008

https://stackoverflow.com/a/25005445/2241008

https://stackoverflow.com/a/36235186/2241008

P.S. swift sources still have a source code for `swift-ide-test` tool (https://github.com/apple/swift/tree/master/tools/swift-ide-test), so another way to see contents of swiftmodules will be in compiling this tool, but I did not investigated this solution any further.

Comment: Seem to no longer work: `Compiler-internal integrated REPL has been removed; use the LLDB-enhanced REPL instead.`

Answer (score 2):

As mentioned on the [Swift forums](https://forums.swift.org/t/reproducible-swiftmodule/30017), you can get a textual representation of a swift module using the command `llvm-bcanalyzer -dump`. You can install this using `brew install llvm` and the man page is [here](https://www.llvm.org/docs/CommandGuide/llvm-bcanalyzer.html).

Answer (score 1):

**Open a .swiftmodule file**

[[.swiftmodule]](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67130959/4770877)

You are able to:

1. add this framework into framework
2. import the framework `import <module_name>`
3. `Jump to Definition`